# Asp.net Identity 2 custom user and custom table name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to customize `IdentityUser` with a couple of extra fields

```
public class User : IdentityUser 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And changing the name of the table

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Auth_Users", "web");
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Auth_Users", "web");
}
```

Pretty straightforward, it works, I have my table `web.Auth_Users`. The bad thing is that the other tables containing user id, so `AspNetUsersClaim`, `AspNetUserLogins` and `AspNetUsersRole`, add a column named `IdentityUser_Id` that is always set to `NULL`

[image]

Why? Where does it come from and how can I avoid it to be created?

Comment: Before you created "IdentityUser", it was the entity "User", right?

Comment: It's the opposite, `IdentityUser` was right before I created `User`.
Anyway I should have removed the `IdentityUser` column name translation as per @CodeNotFound answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this weird column because of this line `modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Auth_Users", "web");`

Just remove it. Finally you must have this code :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Auth_Users", "web");
}
```